# How to address space in an upload file name

Tags: .net

My application could accept upload file with spaces in file names. The problem is when I generate hyperlink to those files, the space within their file names really stopped me from doing this.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("e:/asdf");
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");
if (rgFiles != null)
{
    sb.Append("<span class='SubTitle'>Your attachments list:</span>");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
    {
       sb.Append("<br><a href=e:\\asdf\\" + fi.Name + ">" + fi.Name + "</a>");
    }
}
else
{
    sb.Append("You don't have any attachment yet.");
}
```

Shoud I replace all the space to underscore? Well, I don't like this way. But if I want to add quote to the fi.name it won't display any filenames.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more: why can't you add quotes around the url? I.e.: `sb.Append("<br><a href='e:\\asdf\\" + fi.Name + "'>" + fi.Name + "</a>");` (note the single quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put quotes around the entire url:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
   sb.Append("<br><a href='e:\\asdf\\" + fi.Name + "'>" + fi.Name + "</a>");
}
```

This way, if your path has spaces, resulting HTML will look like this:

```
<br><a href='e:\asdf\your file name.txt'>your file name.txt</a>
```

Comment: Damn, I should add the quote to the right place, which I added before </a>, that's why it doesn't display anything like I said in my post. You rock! Man.

Answer (score 1):

Just [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) the filename. It will replace the spaces with valid URL equivalents (`%20` or `+`).

```
sb.FormatAppend("<br><a href=e:\\asdf\\{0}>{1}</a>", 
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fi.Name),
                fi.Name);
```

Comment: Dude, it doesn't work, e.g the file name "CC AP and Svc Pkg-FCRA March 2011.pdf" will be encoded to "CC+AP+and+Svc+Pkg-FCRA+March+2011.pdf". Apprently, when you click the link, server could not find a file with a name "CC+AP+and+Svc+Pkg-FCRA+March+2011.pdf"

Comment: @Steven - You appear to be trying to access a local file. Why are you not using a [`file://` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)?

Comment: Actually the location is in another server, I mapped the path. But it has nothing to do with the file name. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces can be represented as `%20` in HTML. Try replacing them with that.

But ideally, you should escape the names with an XML/HTML parser.

Comment: Doesn't work man, after replace space to %20, it still can not find the file.